# How to update a Java HashMap with new Map

Tags: java, hashmap

How can I update a Java `HashMap` with a new Map? I have a requirement where I have to iteratively update a `HashMap` with a subsequent new map I get.
Update has two parts

1. Checks if the latest map has any new key not present in the final map and puts them
2. Updates the keys which are already present in the final map with the latest map values.

Currently, I am doing this

```
currentDataMap.forEach(finalMap::putIfAbsent);
finalMap.replaceAll(currentDataMap::getOrDefault);
```

Is there better way or one step way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like all you need is a single call to [`putAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll-java.util.Map-):

```java
finalMap.putAll(currentDataMap)
```